# What is the best CI/CD solution for deploying Node.js with PM2?

Tags: continuous-integration

Currently, my team has to connect SSH to a server then update code, build it and start an app by PM2 CLI.
I'm finding a better solution to integrate a CICD into our workflows so that team members just need to commit code into Git repo.
I use Git, ExpressJS and PM2 in Ubuntu 18.
Thanks and looking forward your advice.